# How can I get mathematica to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan\left(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=−n\cot\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+n\theta\right)$?

Tags: summation, trigonometry

How can I get Mathematica to prove $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan\left(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=−n\cot\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+n\theta\right)$    (1)?

```
Sum[Tan[T + (k \[Pi])/m], {k, 0, m - 1}]
```

*see [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346368/sum-of-tangent-functions-where-arguments-are-in-specific-arithmetic-series/346382#346382)  of (1) and slight [variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1094930/is-there-any-identity-for-sum-k-0n-1-tanxka) here.

Comment: "Solve" as in find the values of some variable? If it's an identity, you already have a proof, so what's the point? Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: To add the the comment by @MichaelE2, if you try `SumConvergence[Tan[T + (k \[Pi])/n], k]` it yields `False`. Is it possible that there assumption for some quantities that you forgot to mention?

Comment: In any case, just to get you started you can try the following: `test1[n_] := Sum[Tan[T + (k \[Pi])/n], {k, 0, n - 1}]
test2[n_] := -n Cot[(n \[Pi])/2 + n T] ` and then check `Table[test1[n], {n, 1, 2}] - Table[test2[n], {n, 1, 2}] // TrigExpand` which gives `{0, 0}` and higher specific values for `n` which give `{0, 0,0,...,0,0,....0}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Edited by me.

Comment: One way is :``Integrate[Sum[D[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], \[Theta]], {k, 0, n - 1}], \[Theta]] // ExpandAll``

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk that's very useful, thanks.

Comment: In this case integrational constans is zero. This is not always true.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk "integrational constans is zero" I'll keep that in mind for other cases and check first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with Mathematica as follows. First, on the domain of the function of `\[Theta]` defined by `Sum[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] +  n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*\[Theta]]` its derivative equals zero as the result of

```
FullSimplify[D[Sum[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] + 
n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*\[Theta]], \[Theta]], Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `0`

assures us. Second, let us determine

```
FunctionDomain[n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*\[Theta]], \[Theta]]
```

> `NotElement[((n*Pi)/2 + n*\[Theta])/Pi, Integers]`

and

```
FunctionPeriod[n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*\[Theta]], \[Theta]]
```

> `Pi/n`

In any case, the point `\[Theta]=Pi/(4n)` belongs to this domain as well as to the domain of `Sum[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], {k, 0, n - 1}]`. The latter statement follows from

```
FunctionDomain[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], \[Theta]]
```

> `1/2 + ((k \[Pi])/n + \[Theta])/\[Pi] \[NotElement] Integers`

Third, `Sum[Tan[\[Theta] + k*Pi/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] +  n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*\[Theta]]` is a constant (perhaps, depending on `n`) on each interval of its domain (which is a periodic set). We find this constant by substituting `\[Theta]==Pi/(4n)` into the sum:

```
 FindSequenceFunction[Table[FullSimplify[Sum[Tan[Pi/(4 n) + k*Pi/n], {k, 0, n - 1}, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] PositiveIntegers] + 
n*Cot[n*Pi/2 + n*Pi/(4 n)]], {n, 1, 10}], n]
```

> `0`